# Image Resize package - Lazziya.ImageResize for asp.net core razor page generate error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using Image Resize package - Lazziya.ImageResize v3 in asp.net core (razor page) application to upload the image then resize to 600x400 dimension.

Image which is uploaded is 1181x 1575 pixels WxH dimension.

First part of the code which uploads the image is working fine but error is generate inside Lazziya.ImageResize function `ResizeUploadedFile(filePath);`.

Error is generate by `img.ScaleByWidth(600).SaveAs(path, 95);`
even if i use `img.ScaleAndCrop(600,400).SaveAs(path);` it shows the same error.

I am not sure why its generating this error as i am using function as per documentation

```
private string ProcessUploadedFile()
{
    string uniqueFileName = null;
    string filePath = null;

    if (NewsImageForUpload != null)
    {
        string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images/news");
        uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + NewsImageForUpload.FileName;
         filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
       // string fullPath = filePath.ToString();
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            NewsImageForUpload.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
    ResizeUploadedFile(filePath);
    return uniqueFileName;
}

private void  ResizeUploadedFile(string filePath)
{
   // string filePath = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images/news");
   // filePath = Path.Combine(uniqueFileName, uniqueFileName);



    string path = Path.Combine(filePath);
    using (var img = Image.FromFile(path))
    {
        img.ScaleByWidth(600).SaveAs(path, 95);
    }
}
```

http://demo.ziyad.info/en/ImageResize

**ERROR DETAILS ***

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
System.Drawing.Image.Save(string filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
    Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing 
    ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
        System.Drawing.Image.Save(string filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
        LazZiya.ImageResize.SaveImage.SaveAs(Image img, string path, int quality)
        BookListRazor.Pages.Admin.News.NewsCreateModel.ResizeUploadedFile(string filePath) in NewsCreate.cshtml.cs
                    img.ScaleByWidth(600).SaveAs(path, 95);
BookListRazor.Pages.Admin.News.NewsCreateModel.ProcessUploadedFile() in NewsCreate.cshtml.cs
                ResizeUploadedFile(filePath);
BookListRazor.Pages.Admin.News.NewsCreateModel.OnPost() in NewsCreate.cshtml.cs
                            News.NewsImage = ProcessUploadedFile();
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert<T>(object taskAsObject)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: are you using linux or windows host? There is a known issue on linux with possible work around as described here https://github.com/LazZiya/ImageResize/issues/1

Comment: I am using windows  & VS 2019. I am not sure why this is happening it should be very simple to implement. also to mention i am using window 7 as my OS. could that be an issue

Comment: Did you tried different pictures? some pictures contains special encodings that may cause similar problems. It would be better if you can share a sample with the picture so I can check for the issue.

Comment: @LazZiya, I have tried different picture and different methods each method gives me error... I will update my question with image sample..

Comment: Its working fine now i was making simple mistake, as input file name & output file name was same.. after i renamed the output filename it works like a charge..

Comment: glad to know it worked :)